# Code for a user specify channel for bot to post in. (Discord.py)

Tags: python, database, discord, bots, discord.py

I am making a bot, that auto posts memes from reddit, to a specified channel.
The only problem is, I have no idea on how to make a command that will let the user customize what channel they want that task to be posted to and get the id.

I tried

```py
@client.command()
async def memer config(ctx):
    await client.send('Where do you want the automemer to post?')
```

This obviously did not work because I had no clue how to get the message that the person who executed the command, and to check if it was a valid channel mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is like this:

1. Person uses command `memer config`
2. Bot replies with `set current channel as meme channel`
3. Your script savze the channel id (`ctx.channel.id`) somewhere (in an SQL database would be ideal)
4. Retrieve the channel id associated with the user's id when needed, `channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)`
5. Post them memes using `await channel.send("them memes")`

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks, my bot should be online and released to the public soon!

Comment: Cool :) glad i could help. Also could you mark my response as the answer